# How to plot matplotlib plots as tables in python(hdf5 tables)

Tags: observational-astronomy, data-analysis, python, hubble-telescope, astropy

I have extracted the data from a fits file and plotted a spectra.i need to do the same for multiple fits files .how can I  store the resultant spectra's  as a hdf5 table or fits table?
And which format is better for storing such datas

Please help !

Comment: This might be better as a question in stackoverflow, as it seems to be more about coding than astronomy. Many of us are active there, as well, so there are probably people who can help.

Comment: Hi Walker and *Welcome to Stack Exchange!* There are [almost 200 sites to choose from](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday) and one of them (as Jim points out) is Stack Overflow, which in fact has an [astropy tag](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday) which is on "665 questions
5 asked this month, 101 this year" but there are of course Astropy users here. No matter where you ask, it would be good to add a little more specific information (e.g. file sizes if that's a concern) and never ask for "which is better?" for several reasons:

Comment: 1) the question might be very quickly down-voted and/or closed for asking a question that is "likely to attract primarily opinion-based answers" and 2) there may be down votes and comments like "how do you define best?" followed by the question being quickly closed for "unclear what you're asking". So try to formulate your question in a way that it can potentially have a right answer, even though multiple answers may be posted.  Also, people may quickly ask "what have you tried so far and why didn't it work?" then down vote for lack of prior research.